# Heap sort it not working or incorrect calculation

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, heapsort, recursive-datastructures

The max-heap function is working fine but heapsort is not working.

When I run this code. it shows incorrect calculation.

```
Your input is:
9 79 42 86 33 75

Your max-heap is:
86 79 42 75 33 9

Ascending numerical order:
86 79 42 75 33 9
```

As you can see my last output, the Ascending numerical order is the same value as max-heap but this is not what I am expecting.

My task is that I have to sort a number from the max-heap. Also, I have to swap first and last element from the max-heap array and then ignore the last element. Also, once the last element is ignored I have to do max-heap function again.

An example of how the calculation works. max-heap is: 86, 79, 42, 75, 33, 9. In the sorting section, I have to swap first and last element and then ignore the last element, so the heap sort result should be: 9, 79, 42, 75, 33, [86] **(square bracket mean ignored or removed)**. I have to do max-heap again from the previous sorting. The second max-heap result would be 79, 75, 9, 42, 33. when I come back to the sorting I have to swap the first and last element and then ignore the last element again so the max-heap is 79, 75, 9, 42, 33 and the heap sort result should be: 33, 75, 9, 42, [79], [86]. I have to do the same step all over again until all the number sorted.

An example of output that I want to display on:

My input is 9, 79, 42, 86, 33, 75

Max- heap should be: 86, 79, 42, 75, 33, 9.

Ascending number should be: 9, 33, 42, 75, 79, 86.

For more example, Please visit the website https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Example, See example 2 - Sorting

And Here the code of incorrect calculation:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int heap[30];

void main()
{
int n, index, parent, flag, dummy;
n = 7; //size of table

// user input number
for (index = 1; index < 7; index++) 
{
    cout << "Enter value " << index << ": ";
    cin >> heap[index];
}

// output for user element
cout << "\nYour input is:\n";
for (index = 1; index < 7; index++) 
{
    cout << heap[index] << " ";
}

flag = 1;

while (flag == 1)
{
    flag = 0;

    //heapify
    for (index = 7; index >1; index--)
    {
        parent = index / 2;
        if (heap[parent] < heap[index])
        {
            dummy = heap[parent];
            heap[parent] = heap[index];
            heap[index] = dummy;
            flag = 1;
        }

        // Sorting --> swap first and last of the array and then ignore the 
        //last array and reheap from above until all number sorted.

        while (heap[0] >= 1)
        {
            int last = heap[0];
            int temp1 = heap[1];
            heap[1] = heap[last - 1];
            heap[last - 1] = temp1;
            heap[0]--;
        }
    }
}

cout << "\n\nYour max-heap is:\n";
for (index = 1; index < 7; index++) // output for after heap
{
    cout << heap[index] << " ";
}

cout << "\n\nAscending numerical order:\n";
for (index = 1; index < 7; index++) //output for sorting.
{
    cout << heap[index] << " ";
}

getchar();
getchar();
}
```

Also the code that I can not change or replace which are

```
    while (flag == 1)
{
    flag = 0;

    //heapify
    for (index = 6; index >1; index--)
    {
        parent = index / 2;
        if (heap[parent] < heap[index])
        {
            dummy = heap[parent];
            heap[parent] = heap[index];
            heap[index] = dummy;
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are most likely doing this for practice, but if you ever need a heap in the real world, take a look at [`std::make_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) and the related functions.

Comment: - hit, This is not practice. Also, I can not change heap function code from the above  which is     for (index = 7; index >1; index--)
    {
        parent = index / 2;
        if (heap[parent] < heap[index])
        {
            dummy = heap[parent];
            heap[parent] = heap[index];
            heap[index] = dummy;
            flag = 1;
        } And this is my assginment, only i have to do is add sorting by using heap

Comment: I am new here, I am sorry that i dont know how to display code in this comment. Also, I want to add new line and i press enter but this make my comment submit.

Comment: Code formatting in comments works by using backticks (`\`code\``), but not on multiple lines. You should also take the sorting part out of the *heapify* part - do that after you've printed the heap, or you'll get a weird inconsistent state. Only then can we see if your code actually works

Comment: It's generally best to edit the initial question to add information rather than putting it in comments.

Comment: I take the sorting part out of heapify and place on after the print max-heap. I test it and the result is same problem. And thank you for tell me how to do it.

Comment: I try formatting the code but doesnt work

Comment: @user4581301 that is good idea but how do i edit the question?

Comment: Use the [edit link under the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50263013/edit)

Comment: @Sam So you wrote code, you know what the code is supposed to do, but it isn't doing what you want it to do.  So what debugging have you done?  Have you used your debugger to step through the program to see where it deviates from your plan?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No this code from my teacher and I have to add a statement that sorting number by using heapsort. And I have tried debugger but I still don't understand how it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many bugs in your code.

First one i have noticed is in your while loop

```
while (heap[0] >= 1) //heap[0] = 0 since you declared your array statically
    {
        int last = heap[0]; // last = 0
        int temp1 = heap[1];
        heap[1] = heap[last - 1]; //trying to find element heap[-1] ERROR
        heap[last - 1] = temp1; //heap[-1] = heap[1]
        heap[0]--; //heap[0] = -1 why?
    }
```

Second one is that you are starting from index 1 and go to index 6 in your input loop (first for loop in code), but when you are trying to make some difference in your heap in third for loop you are starting from index 7 and you go to index 2.

I couldn't find a way in your code so i will post mine. It is following the algorithm in that wiki page you posted.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



void build_heap(int *heap, int index)
{
    if(index>1)
    {
       int new_input = heap[index], tmp = 0;
    //since your index starts from 1 and goes up to n in heap
    //parent from index k is (k%2==1) ? (k-1)/2 : k/2
    if(index % 2 == 1)
        index--;
    if(heap[index/2] < new_input)
    {

        tmp = heap[index/2];
        heap[index/2] = new_input;
        heap[index] = tmp;
        build_heap(heap, index/2);
       }
    }
}

void make_order_in_heap(int *heap, int n)
{
if(n>1)
{
    int index = 1;
    int child_index;
    bool work = true;

    while(work && index < n)
    {
        //finding child_index
        if( index * 2 + 1 <= n)
        {
            child_index = heap[index*2] > heap[index*2+1] ? index*2 : index*2+1;
        }
        else if(index * 2 <= n)
        {
            child_index = index*2;
        }
        else
        {
            //this index has no  children
            return;
        }
        work = false;
        if(heap[child_index] > heap[index])
        {
            int tmp = heap[index];
            heap[index] = heap[child_index];
            heap[child_index] = tmp;
            index = child_index;
            work = true;
        }
    }

}
}

void swap_first_and_last(int *heap, int n)
{
if(n>1)
{
    int tmp = heap[1];
    heap[1] = heap[n];
    heap[n] = tmp;
}
}

void sort_heap(int *heap, int n)
{
if(n>1)
{
    swap_first_and_last(heap, n);
    //we swaped first and last element in heap with n elements
    //so now first element in heap of n-1 elements is not on his      possiton
    make_order_in_heap(heap, n-1);
    sort_heap(heap, n-1);
}
}

int main()
{
int heap[30];
int n, index, parent, flag, dummy;
n = 7; 

for (index = 1; index <= n; index++) 
{
    cout << "Enter value " << index << ": ";
    cin >> heap[index];
    build_heap(heap, index);
}

cout << "\nYour input is:\n";
for (index = 1; index <= n; index++) 
{
    cout << heap[index] << " ";
}


sort_heap(heap, n);

cout << "\n Sorted array is:\n";
for (index = 1; index <= n; index++) 
{
    cout << heap[index] << " ";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works for me, Thank you for your help. Also, I found a solution, I just added few lines for the heapsort without calling any void function I would like to share my solution with other people who have the same problem as me but unfortunately, I don't know to share the code in this comment. :(

Comment: you can not write code in comment, but you can answer your own question

Comment: You can accept or like an answer if it helped you 